# How to use NSzombie in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory-management, nszombie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable NSZombie on Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-on-xcode-4)

My application is crashing a lot! How do I find the error through NSZombie?

Could someone give me step by step instructions to use NSZombie or the Valgrind tool to find memory errors, reference errors, etc.