# Reading Stacktrace in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I don't like real-time debugging much, but if it's necessary I'll do it.

Is there any way to figure out what **line of code** a StackTrace in Objective-C refers to? What about the **variable** it refers to? For instance:

```
2010-05-13 19:39:11.673 Thingers[21003:207] *** -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0ebb0
2010-05-13 19:39:11.674 Thingers[21003:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0ebb0'
2010-05-13 19:39:11.675 Thingers[21003:207] Stack: (
    29303899
    ...
    11130
)
```

I see that we're talking about sending a `count` message to something that doesn't have it (maybe it's a NSCFString?), but is there any way to figure out what a/the named reference to that instance (0x3b0ebb0) refers to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack here is mostly useless. What is important here is

> `-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0ebb0`

This means a `-count` is sent to a string. This is usually caused by memory management bugs. You could [enable NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) and run the program again to see what is being over-released.

Also, use Build → Build and Analyze in Xcode to find out possible memory management bugs in statically.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Although this this case I really am sending a `count` message to an object that doesn't have that selector, it's good to know that NSZombie exists.

Comment: @yar: Oh. Don't ignore the compiler warnings :).