# App Crashes Loading View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code in my AppDelegate.h file:

```
@class mainViewController;  
@class AboutViewController;  
@interface iSearchAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {  
    UIWindow *window;  
    mainViewController *viewController;  
 AboutViewController *aboutController;  
 UINavigationController *nav;  

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet mainViewController *viewController;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AboutViewController *aboutController;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *nav;   
[...IBActions declared here...]  
@end
```

Then, in my .m file:

```
@implementation iSearchAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController, aboutController, settingsData, nav, engines;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {      

  [window addSubview:nav.view];
  [window addSubview:aboutController.view];
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];  

  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

-(IBAction)switchToHome{ 
  [window bringSubviewToFront:viewController.view];
} 
-(IBAction)switchToSettings{  
  [window bringSubviewToFront:nav.view];  
}  
-(IBAction)switchToAbout{  
  [window bringSubviewToFront:aboutController.view]; 
}


- (void)dealloc {  
   [viewController release];  
   [aboutController release];  
   [nav release];  
   [window release];  
   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Somehow, when I run the app, the main view presents itself fine... however, when I try to execute the actions to switch views, the app crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

So, I think it has something to do with memory management, but I'm not quite sure.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Link to screenshots of code is here: [link](http://www.igramsey.com/uploads/errors/)...

***SOLVED:*** I fixed the issue by taking out the IBActions and making them into regular methods... apparently, XCode doesn't like it when you put IBActions in an AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... message sent to deallocated instance ...

If it is memory management, my first step would be to [enable `NSZombie`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) and discover what was being messaged after being dealloc'ed. Two obvious things I can think of:

1. Uninitialised property/variable.
2. De-allocated (non-retained) property

Have your controls in interface builder been connected to the `IBAction`s?

Comment: Thanks- I fixed the problem- apparently, it was the IBActions that was causing the app to crash, I guess you can't have IBActions with an App Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are invoking `[iSearchAppDelegate performSelector:withObject:withObject:]`. You haven't shown that code here but that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Is it possible that that method is invoked by another method?
Because I definitely never typed a "performSelector" method...