# Objective-C: Is there any way to find out what kind of object resides at a particular memory address?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Coming from Java and Python, I am not so well versed in memory management, but is there any way to find out what kind of object resides at a particular memory address?

I am asking because my application terminated with a cryptic message that reads:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber encodedURLParameterString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x164840'`

and would like to get some clues as to what is going wrong.

And if that is not possible, some debugging techniques for such error messages would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT: Follow Up Concern (MOVED [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270071/nsstring-string-somestring-vs-nsstring-string-nsstring-alloc-initwith))**

After some investigation of the framework that I have been using, I came across something that I don't really understand.

If I have a method

```
- (void) myMethod:(NSString *)string {
    [Object anothermethodWithString:string];
}
```

and I call

```
[Object myMethod:@"this is a string"];
```

Do I need to do something like

```
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", string];
[Object anothermethodWithString:string2];
[string2 release];
```

instead of the way I had myMethod before? It seems like the string I passed through the parameter of my method got released somewhere, and doing that solves my problem. I guess I don't really understand what exactly @"string" does in terms of memory. Is it like an auto-released NSString?

Comment: There is something wrong with the definition of myMethod in your follow-up question. What looks like a call to anothermethod... is not valid Objective-C. In any case: no you don't have to create a new string when you pass it on. Another thing: since your follow-up is unrelated to your original question, you should post it as a separate question. That will be more useful for other people with similar concerns.

Comment: @Felixyz Whoops, sorry. I wrote the example method when my brain was fried from trying to debug. It should be fixed now. And thanks for the suggestion. I'll re-post it, especially since the behavior of my code tells me that the string is somehow being lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, from the error, the object type at that memory address is NSDecimalNumber. You got an error because you called encodedURLParameterString on a NSDecimalNumber which does not have a method with that name.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea how to read those error statements. Thanks! I looked at the framework that I have been using and found where encodedURLParameterString is called. I think I found my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In gdb you could type

```
po <address>
```

to find out the object's description *if* it's really an Objective-C object.

But in your case it sounds more like you're sending message to an already deallocated object, which will give wrong result on the object's type. Try to [enable NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) to show what kind of object it actually is.

Comment: Thanks for you response! I found my error by inspection, but I will definitely look into NSZombie.

Answer (score 3):

This type of error is often caused by a "dangling pointer", the result of keeping a pointer reference to an object after it has been deallocated. If an other object is instantiated in the (now empty) memory space and you subsequently send a message through the dangling pointer, you get an error like that you've observed. This particular error is caused by sending a message `encodedURLParameterString` to an `NSDecimalNumber`.

The fact that the beginning of the `struct objc_object` of an `NSDecimalNumber` instance is in the memory location previously occupied by the object you think you're referencing isn't of much consequence. You really care about where the dangling reference is held, and why the object was deallocated before you expected. You can [enable `NSZombie`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) tracking, which keeps deallocated objects alive and stops in the debugger when you try to send them a message. You can also investigate the stack trace from the site of the crash. The previous stack frame will likely point you to where the offending message was sent from, and thence to the reference that was used.

Once you've identified where the dangling reference is being kept, you should check whether that reference is correctly retained (to keep the object alive).

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I have a question about dangling pointers. I just updated my question statement.

Comment: Your update is really an unrelated question. The short answer is no, you don't need to modify your code. Other code should retain ownership in your string if it needs to. You should read the Cocoa Memory Management Programming guide (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Then re-read it. Print it out, put it under your pillow. Then read it again. Seriously. Once you grok its contents, all of your questions will be answered.