# iPhone SDK: NSMutableArray count causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

This is really twisting my mind… I'm trying to access an NSMutableArray in an IBAction which I defined in viewDidLoad. Unfortunately I keep getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I'm new to all this so I'd really appreciate some insight in what I'm doing wrong.

Below find the corresponding code excerpts.

**CounterViewController.h:**

```
@interface CounterViewController : UIViewController{
 NSMutableArray *countHistoryArray;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *countHistoryArray;
```

**CounterViewController.m:**

```
@implementation CounterViewController
@synthesize countHistoryArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 //Fill array with some dummy data
 self.countHistoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
 CurrentCount *historicCount = [[[CurrentCount alloc]
         initWithCount:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:22]
         description:@"Testcount"
         dateAndTime:now] autorelease];

 [self.countHistoryArray addObject: historicCount];

 //Do some logging - everything is working fine here!
 NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray description]); 

}


//Later on we click on a button and want to use the array
- (IBAction)doSomeStuff {  
    //Let's look at the array again - and now it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
 NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray description]);
}
```

Thanks a lot!
Manuel

---

*EDIT* Additional code as asked for by @jamapag

**CurrentCount.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CurrentCount : NSObject {
    NSNumber *counterLevel;
    NSString *description;
    NSDate *dateAndTime;
}

- (id)initWithCount:(NSNumber *)newCounterLevel description:(NSString *)newDescription dateAndTime:(NSDate *)newDateAndTime;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *counterLevel;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDate *dateAndTime;

@end
```

**CurrentCount.m**

```
#import "CurrentCount.h"


@implementation CurrentCount
@synthesize counterLevel;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize dateAndTime;

- (id)initWithCount:(NSNumber *)newCounterLevel description:(NSString *)newDescription dateAndTime:(NSDate *)newDateAndTime{
    self = [super init];
    if(nil != self){
        self.counterLevel = newCounterLevel;
        self.description  = newDescription;
        self.dateAndTime  = newDateAndTime;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) dealloc{
    self.counterLevel = nil;
    self.description  = nil;
    self.dateAndTime  = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere, somewhere in between the two calls. However, this code has a leak at `self.countHistoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` -- you `alloc` the array, the property accessor will `retain`, but you don't `release`. You should either assign directly to the ivar or add an `autorelease`. It's probably worth checking for other questionable uses of `self.countHistoryArray = ...` which might be causing the trouble.

Comment: I do `-(void)dealloc {[self.countHistoryArray release];}` which I think does the job. Am I wrong?

Comment: In `-dealloc`, you should either call `-release` on the ivar itself: `[countHistoryArray release]`, or you should set the property to nil, which will release whatever was previously stored in the ivar, having exactly the same effect: `self.countHistoryArray = nil`. I prefer the second technique personally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure that your code actually looks like this?

```
- (IBAction)doSomeStuff {  
    //Let's look at the array again - and now it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray description]);
}
```

Your question title says "NSMutableArray count causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS" - if that line of code actually says `NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray count]);`, you'll almost certainly get a crash, since `NSLog` will attempt to treat a primitive type (the type returned by `-[NSArray count]`) as an object. In order to use `-[NSArray count]` in `NSLog`, use `%u` instead of `%@`:

```
- (IBAction)doSomeStuff {  
    // This time it should work!
    NSLog(@"Array Count = %u", [self.countHistoryArray count]);
}
```

Comment: Ha! Very good, that works! Thank you!
(I did change from count to description somewhere during time).

What I do not understand though is, `NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray description]);` is now working, too. You say it can't work, but it does. Strange stuff…

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [self.countHistoryArray description]);` will work - my wording may have been slightly ambiguous. In an `NSLog` style format string, you should use `%@` for any Obj-C object, and an appropriate format symbol for any C primitives (`%u` for unsigned ints, `%f` for floats etc). Also, you can just use `NSLog(@"%@", self.countHistoryArray)`, since `NSLog` will call `description` on the object for you automatically.

Comment: The reason I thought that this might be the case is because it's a common mistake, which I made many times when I was learning Obj-C (and occasionally still make when I'm tired enough).

Answer (score 0):

Remove **autorelease** from:

`currentCount *historicCount = [[[CurrentCount alloc]
         initWithCount:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:22]
         description:@"Testcount"
         dateAndTime:now] autorelease];`

Comment: Thanks, but… I did try that before - and now again. Still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: No, the `autorelease` is fine, don't mess with that.

Comment: @walkytalky Thanks, that's what I was thinking, too. But I must think wrong somewhere so it was worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accidentally releasing `countHistoryArray` somewhere. Try removing all calls to it except for those two you showed. Additionally you can try enabling [zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) to debug the problem.

Oh and by the way you probably don't really want a public NSMutableArray property and if you do you probably want it to be copy, not retain. Otherwise incapsulation kinda goes down the drain.

Comment: Thank you! Problem one is solved.
I'll look into the copy/retain thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been solved and accepted but its for others who are or will face this issue.

I was facing the same issue, I tried all solutions but no solution worked for me. The project I am working on is NON-ARC.

I tried and made a simple change in property

Previously my property for NSMUTABLEARRAY was

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray * dataArray;
```

I changed it to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * dataArray;
```

**Changed it from ASSIGN to RETAIN**

And it solved my problem