# How can I debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS from an invalidated NSTimer

Tags: memory-leaks, nstimer

I've got a repeating NSTimer that I invalidate manually some time before I dealloc the object that owns the callback that is invoked by the timer.  I verify that when I invalidate the timer, the callback is not being called anymore.  When the object deallocs, an instant later I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  The crash is correlated with whether I invalidate the timer or not, i.e. if I don't invalidate it, there is no crash.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  I don't see why the timer would try to access the callback for the dealloc'ed object, which is what *seems* to be happening.  I'm at a loss how to debug this further. The callstack just says:

```
#0  0x02f05c93 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x00000001 in ??
#2  0x02d255fa in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#3  0x02d248a8 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#4  0x037de89d in GSEventRunModal
#5  0x037de962 in GSEventRun
#6  0x00863372 in UIApplicationMain
#7  0x00002e40 in main at main.m:13
```

UPDATE: I have determined it is not the timer but a leak resulting from my parent object calling dealloc (the non-invalidating timer was preventing dealloc from calling).  It would still be useful to hear advice on how to debug things when I hit a wall with the callstack, if it is even possible, so I'll leave this question up.

Answer (score 4):

When you invalidate an `NSTimer`, the receiver sends a `release` to the `target` and `userInfo` parameters of `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`.  Is it possible you are referring to these objects or have some incorrect memory-management with one of these objects?

One way to debug this is to make use of [NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to NSZombie.  I discovered the problem wasn't the NSTimer after all, but rather the fact that when I *properly* invalidate them all, my object is able to be dealloc'ed (instead of retained by the timer) and the dealloc itself was causing the crash because of another object.

Comment: Glad you were able to correct the situation.  Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer to help others if they encounter this situation.  Remember, zombies are your friends...at least NSZombies!