# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” with Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am new with iOS Developpement and trying to use Core Data with a TableView.

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using Core Data an TableView. I'm not sure if error comes from Core Data objects or TableView because I don't know were I am in my code.

```
#0  0x0157ea63 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0582ea20 in ?? ()
#2  0x005c100f in -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] ()
#3  0x0047bb00 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] ()
#4  0x004778a7 in -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] ()
#5  0x004842b8 in -[UITableView reloadData] ()
#6  0x00481470 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
#7  0x01ff2451 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#8  0x01ff217c in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#9  0x01feb37c in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#10 0x01feb0d0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#11 0x0201b7d5 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#12 0x013fdfbb in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x013930e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#14 0x0135bbd7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x0135b240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x0135b161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x01a69268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x01a6932d in GSEventRun ()
#19 0x0041942e in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Especially anywhere you are releasing something while building the TableView

Comment: My error was on a release : ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
controller.a = a;
controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
 
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[controller.view initWithFrame:bounds];

[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
//[controller release]; -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably from your TableView, set breakpoints in your datasource method to find out or [set NSZombie environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode)

You will probably discover that your datasource try to access an unallocated object

Comment: Hello VdesmedT, I found that my datasource is exactly trying to access to an unallocated object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then maybe you can set the Accept Flag (Grey check mark on the left) on this answer ;-)