# How to place significant NSLogs in Xcode without typing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, nslog

I don´t know how to debug properly with Xcode.
I received a SIGABRT error in my Objective C Applicatin and am trying to find the reason for it.
Typically Im doing it with NSLogs.
Is there a possibility to generate NSLogs with some Informationen at specific parts of the source.
And , in the case this method of debugging is inefficient, please someone tell me how to debug properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable nszombie 
[How to use NSzombie in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode)