# Exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve got a view controller  containing four buttons..clicking on each button takes you to new view controller containing web view.everything works fine  except when the button is clicked ..it takes you to the web view if i m to navigate back the app quits...in debug mode i ve got dis exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS...below is the code...

```
-(IBAction)Button1
{

WebViewFaceBook *newEnterNameController4 = [[WebViewFaceBookalloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewFaceBook" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController4 animated:YES];

[newEnterNameController4 release];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
    urlAddress2 = @"http://www.facebook.com/livingwaterscf";

    url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress2];

    requestObj2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];

    [webViewFaceBook loadRequest:requestObj2];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you releasing the webView in dealloc? Are you using any delegate methods of the webview?

Checkout [NSZombieEnabled](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html) for your active executable to see some more info on the bad access.

These assignment won't work without declaration of ivars/properties:

```
urlAddress2 = @"http://www.facebook.com/livingwaterscf";

url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress2];

requestObj2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
```

Can you please show us the definition of those in your header file?

**Edit**

Change your declaration of urlAddress2, url2 and requestObj2 to retained properties and set them with `self.urlAddress2 = xxx`, then you can release them in dealloc. The class methods as well as the `@"http://www.facebook.com/livingwaterscf"` return autoreleased instances. If you want to own them you have to retain those and only then you should release them.

If you don't want to own them, and in this case I don't think you need those anywhere else then starting the load of the webview's content, just don't release them in dealloc!

Comment: i ve released my webview in dealloc...i m not using any delgate..just the above code..but still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: So have you set NSZombieEnabled to YES? Anything new then on the console?

Comment: using nszombie got dis message--[CFURL release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6317940
...cud u help me out

Comment: Please show us the declarations as shown in my updated question.

Comment: NSString *urlAddress2;
 NSURL *url2;
 NSURLRequest *requestObj2;
 IBOutlet UIWebView *webViewFaceBook;these are the four declarations and i m deallocating all four in dealloc method

Answer (score 1):

You try to access something that has been deallocated.

Enable [NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) to find out where.

Comment: i ve got dis message...[CFURL release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6317940...cud u help me out

Comment: @user652878 you release `url2` somewhere, but you should not since it is autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

You may be release `url2` in `dealloc` method in your `WebViewFaceBook` controller.

`requestObj2, url2, urlAddress2` already autoreleased. You mustn't release them in dealloc