# zombie logging enable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use NSzombie in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode)

i have problem of crashing in my app but i don't have exactly reason to crash. when i search the problem i find about Zombie logging. but i don't know hoe to use or how to enable..