# Receive unexpected “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access

When i delete cell from table view:This error is occur:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Here i delete object from cell and its event from calander:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        lovkid *mykids = (lovkid *)[appDelegate.actionarray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        appDelegate.actionId = mykids.Id;

        //delete from calender
        if( [ mykids.Event isEqualToString:@"empty"])
        {
        }
        else
        {
            EKEvent* event2 = [appDelegate.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:mykids.Event];
            if (event2 != nil) 
            {  
                NSError* error = nil;
                [appDelegate.eventStore removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            } 
        }

        //delete end
        [mykids deleteAction];
        [appDelegate.actionarray1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Delete the object from the table.
        [localTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [localTable reloadData];
        a = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        //NSLog(@"test");
    }
```

Delete from db:

```
deleteStmt1 = nil;
    if(deleteStmt1 == nil) 
    {
            const char *sql = "delete from actions where id = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, sql, -1, &deleteStmt1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));

    //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
        sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt1, 1,(int)appDelegate.actionId);

        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt1)) 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));

        sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt1);
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt1);
    }
```

What is the reason behing this error?

Comment: What does the log say?  What line is it crashing on?

Comment: Step one is [enabling NSZombie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841014/zombie-logging-enable/5841041#5841041). After doing this, build and run the app and then tell us the more detailed error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest removing the line:

```
    [localTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If you are reloading the table by `reloadData`, it is not necessary to remove the row that way. The table will be reloaded reflecting the new data source state.

On the other hand, you could investigate `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you are up to a smoother refresh of your table. In that case it makes sense using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

I don't know if this will solve your crash. In case it does not, I suggest you execute under the debugger so you can find out exactly which is the offending statement causing the crash.

Comment: I had to remove the animation as well. Frustrating.