# drawing with finger on UIImageView with a scroll View

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I need to make an UIImageView, on a scroll View, active for touching.
is a little UiimageView 100x50 were people can make the signature.

I am using the same code and it works, but with scroll view it doesn't.
I looked around, but I could not find a code for that.

.h

```
UIImageView *drawImage;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage;
```

.m

```
    @synthesize drawImage;

    - (void)viewDidLoad    {
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1540)];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        button.enabled = YES;
    drawImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchesBegan:)];
    gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [drawImage addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
    [gestureRec release];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(printItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(75, 0, 44, 44);
   [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"print.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        mouseSwiped = NO;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        if ([touch tapCount] == 3) {
            drawImage.image = nil;
            return;
        }

        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
        //  lastPoint.y -=20;// only if signature goes bottom of the screen
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        mouseSwiped = YES;

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
        currentPoint.y -=5; // only if signature goes bottom of the screen


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);

        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 2.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        if ([touch tapCount] == 3) {
            drawImage.image = nil;
            return;
        }

        if(!mouseSwiped) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);

            CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 3.0);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(currentContext, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
            drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    }
```

I tried the NSZombieEnabled and I get a SIGABRIT on the UITouch line on touchesBegan

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 3) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
    //  lastPoint.y -=20;// only if signature goes bottom of the screen
}
```

and a SIGABRIT here, in the int main(int argc, char *argv[]) line

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

I still get the error like before:

```
2011-05-10 22:14:22.509 anamnesiprova[90427:207] -[UITapGestureRecognizer anyObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bd5ba0

2011-05-10 22:14:22.512 anamnesiprova[90427:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer anyObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bd5ba0'
```

Comment: anyone please? what's wrong with the code. thanks

Comment: +1 for tidying up, thanks again.

Comment: Okay, can you enable NSZombieEnabled for your active executable and see if something new turns up instead of `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68adc80` or alike?

Comment: I tried to enable NSZombieEnabled: product/profile/ and in argument in the Enviromental Variables I out NSZombieEnabled YES, but it did not work :(, I do not now what is it this NSZombie, so probably I need to activate it in a different way. thanks again for your help

Comment: Have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) and this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html) it'll help you to get the hang of it.

Comment: @Nick, hello again. I tried different thing with this code and I noticed that. when the source is like -(void) somethig {} it works always, but when the source is like -(void) something : (id) sender {} it never works.

Comment: @Marco yes that's because you have to add a colon to the selector like: `@selector(myMethodToBeCalled:)` this tells the selector to choose a method which expects one parameter. With this you can pass the `(id)sender`

Comment: @Nick, sorry can I put the @ when I put a reply ? I do not want to annoy to much. I added the colon but it crashes, actually the action I am using is this, with NSSet and UIEvent. can it be the problem?      -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: right I think I have to crate an IBAction instead that right, but how can I use touchesbegan as IBAction? tahnks                -(IBAction)touchesbegan:(id)sender;

Comment: @Marco An IBAction is for the action target pattern, for example used with the UIButton, it's meant for controls that inherit from UIControl. UIImageView is not suitable for that. Use a gesture recognizer or subclassing and overwriting the touches methods.

Comment: @NicK, I am still having problem with this code. anyway I noticed that when you touch with one finger the scrollview you can hold the scrolling, so is it possible stop the scrolling with one finger and use a second finger for writing?

Comment: @Marco I don't know, I haven't tried that before. But please let us know if you try and what came out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set `userInteractionEnabled` of your UIImageView to YES.

Another idea would be to add a GestureRecognizer to your imageView, for the beginning a simple one:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethodToBeCalled)];
gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
[gestureRec release];
```

Comment: thanks Nick,  I set the userInteractionEnable YES, but still I do not have any responses from UIImageView.

Comment: @Marco try to set delaysContentTouches of the UIScrollView to NO. If you put NSLogs in your touch methods do they get called at all? I've added some code for a gesture recognizer, try this.

Comment: that's very kind of you. I tried your code, but as soon as I touch my UImageView the app crashes and I get this error:

Comment: I tried this action to check if it works with my UImageView:                               - (void)twoFingersTwoTaps {
  NSLog(@"Action: tap");
} , and it gives me the the correct action without crashing . BUt when I use the touchesbegan action it crashes. thanks for your help

Comment: I am trying UILongPressGestureRecognizer now, so wen u move the finger it repeat the action. I am wondering how to do an action that makes a dot every time I tap the view. -(void) drawdot: (id) sender {} any help please?

Comment: ok I found a solution for that     -(IBAction)swoosh:(id)sender{
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}