# Why is my application freezing when changing views?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have this same code at the end of each view to go to the next:

```
- (IBAction)proceed2 {
    StepThree *one = [[[StepThree alloc] initWithNibName:@"StepThree" bundle:nil]      autorelease];
    one.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:one animated:YES];
}
```

This has worked in every view except this one, and all of my code looks exactly the same except for different step numbers (not always StepThree). I imported "StepThree.h" just as I did in all of them... why is this one giving me problems?

By the way, it is in the line

```
[self presentModalViewController:one animated:YES];
```

and the error is "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"."

Comment: Anything more on the console output?

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: can you dump the full console output, well the last few lines, into your answer?

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Check the stack just before this call, and of course, include full console output as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you post seems correct.

The problems arises presumably due to something in `StepThree` implementation.

A good way to diagnose this kind of bad behavior is enabling "zombies" detection. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode) for details.