# iPhone Crash log from Xcode

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

I've just switched to ARC and am having lots of crashes. Can someone help me read this crash log? is there a difference between this and an exported crash log? It's the first time I've tackled crash logs:

```
Incident Identifier: 0C6906B0-E8CE-4C59-B717-CA8726CF386B
CrashReporter Key:   4099021719b0d972146f97885f14f0054190c0b1
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         iRun_01 [950]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/817F48C2-FD23-4768-87B3-32E4D6B35A41/iRun_01.app/iRun_01
Identifier:      iRun_01
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-06 14:31:45.896 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000010
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31f0cde0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31f0cd22 _objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 6
2   CoreFoundation                  0x320f0e88 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
3   UIKit                           0x32c689fc _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 36
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32174b44 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32172d80 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x321730da __CFRunLoopRun + 754
7   CoreFoundation                  0x320f64d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x320f639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   GraphicsServices                0x32202fe6 GSEventRunModal + 150
10  UIKit                           0x32c8673c UIApplicationMain + 1084
11  iRun_01                         0x000cfea6 main (main.m:14)
12  iRun_01                         0x000cf920 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315643b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x328f4e78 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x328f4b96 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3217441c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32173154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x320f64d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320f639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x30bab128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3217441c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32173154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x320f64d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320f639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x35d1cbc2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x35d1ca8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x35db059a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019c16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3217866a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019c16 _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  NetworkIO
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31564206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3217441c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32173154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x320f64d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320f639e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   MapKit                          0x33752412 0x33744000 + 58386
7   Foundation                      0x35d1ca8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x35db059a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019c16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34019ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31574cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3401409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x3ef82d30    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x0c949028      r3: 0x32c689d9
    r4: 0x0c949000    r5: 0x3ef82d30      r6: 0x3ef82d30      r7: 0x2fecbee4
    r8: 0x0c94961c    r9: 0x0053d150     r10: 0x0c94961c     r11: 0xa3a3a3a3
    ip: 0x3eb834cc    sp: 0x2fecbec0      lr: 0x31f0cd29      pc: 0x31f0cde0
  cpsr: 0x600f0030

Binary Images:
   0xce000 -   0x3b8fff +iRun_01 armv7  <1d007dd1786c320ba6d47f5e1678f7a4> /var/mobile/Applications/817F48C2-FD23-4768-87B3-32E4D6B35A41/iRun_01.app/iRun_01
0x2fecd000 - 0x2feeefff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x308b1000 - 0x308d1fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x30a49000 - 0x30af5fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x30af6000 - 0x30b02fff  Accounts armv7  <d45636e9d2263676b17c2c33ec7e91d3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x30b03000 - 0x312bafff  WebCore armv7  <5a60e1e3f68331e5b426dd4dfeb3def8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x312bb000 - 0x312bffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x312ca000 - 0x312cdfff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x31320000 - 0x3132dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31392000 - 0x313f5fff  IMCore armv7  <8dbf71fc51af3424ac33348db251ba0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x313f6000 - 0x3140bfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2e35ec83cc823bbebf107dc4867e61d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3141b000 - 0x31422fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x314df000 - 0x31562fff  CoreMotion armv7  <5e0f8a464b0736cfaa6cf3a0c1f33f2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x31563000 - 0x31579fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <ac287acb68d032118cd824a51011638d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3157e000 - 0x3157efff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31aa8000 - 0x31ac0fff  iAd armv7  <35b09ad420f73996b11862ba78000587> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x31ac7000 - 0x31bb7fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c77ceeffd75e3bcc9df3bbe91e2dac98> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x31d42000 - 0x31d43fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x31f07000 - 0x31fcdfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d503b4ad04313023bbe76ededd30ed70> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x320df000 - 0x320e6fff  StoreKit armv7  <3a3177565bb4307f92b7d9eb29a927e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x320e7000 - 0x321fefff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a2dbc131fdc0364e822339ca2926b6e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x321ff000 - 0x3220afff  GraphicsServices armv7  <08bfaa5766853884a09cd70f5ae37017> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32241000 - 0x3241efff  AudioToolbox armv7  <59dd50551a893636b94bf4505a62ef97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32431000 - 0x3246dfff  IMFoundation armv7  <782ea3e246093c56a7bc04f60c8ca1b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x32499000 - 0x324e2fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <80836b34a3ef389d82f0fa55cadccc61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x324e3000 - 0x324e5fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x324e6000 - 0x3251dfff  Security armv7  <195ed72ea7583470958d72652bd84f03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32531000 - 0x32534fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <48fe217ed667308bb9413c11f5b5b31d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3254a000 - 0x3261afff  WebKit armv7  <b79a797a66723db89d6c2f89c0925cf8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x32737000 - 0x3278efff  CoreAudio armv7  <d0d388a7373036a08561809242f5a5f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3278f000 - 0x327cefff  QuickLook armv7  <2f7ad2dfd31f3473a89156da7f70740c> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x327cf000 - 0x327d9fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x328ab000 - 0x328d0fff  OpenCL armv7  <051a834ba5583f47876f0c8b9a1e3dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x328e8000 - 0x328fefff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <86ed1499ae1e3f5ba389e657f6a23ced> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32911000 - 0x32915fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3293b000 - 0x3295efff  MobileSync armv7  <f95bb1140fb730d09fe7d83cd1b2c78b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3295f000 - 0x329b5fff  GMM armv7  <a88c7f8dc6d7322c904325ffa551bf1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x329b8000 - 0x32afdfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <649b7b4a430a340b8c2b85c6fb4e1369> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32aff000 - 0x32b15fff  EAP8021X armv7  <3f7bd850face343495b2c542ef63d44d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x32b62000 - 0x32b71fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <09c637a85e3d3af488e59ced95a5a916> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32b82000 - 0x32b88fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <18472eec0dfa3aa993f4ae7f34ec5c52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32b89000 - 0x32ba6fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <8e5dd82833293382a08f11517e9dcb9b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x32c4b000 - 0x32c4ffff  Marco armv7  <5a1a8ed254ec3fb899ae70121a9c69b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x32c50000 - 0x32c54fff  CertUI armv7  <49cd072db1c7362383e0f5b15c039025> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32c55000 - 0x330eefff  UIKit armv7  <87348d5d0d043aa095840765b6d73999> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x330f5000 - 0x3310ffff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <3c71cf1ffe013b179a6a905bdf69ff8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x3319b000 - 0x331d0fff  DataAccess armv7  <26ef3aa5d3613987bcb5b5a8644a55bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x331d1000 - 0x331dcfff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x331e0000 - 0x33286fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <90b13f7f5d6c38f68efba5944faa2ad4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33287000 - 0x332ebfff  MessageUI armv7  <1da68e2025c938d1bcbb8d2cff5e5032> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x332ec000 - 0x332f3fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <f6d1bb9e4b60392f834d4e0ee35105cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33323000 - 0x3335ffff  iCalendar armv7  <59d80290d8733df8a6310da65b497fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33360000 - 0x33484fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <322e347adc08308ca55fc7de9598248c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33498000 - 0x33586fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <0f52661fd7af3a448b95f8d93d20f3f7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33656000 - 0x33659fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <d7f346d1c62d35b18fec919efc67eb84> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x336d0000 - 0x336d6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <4e3671438f71326bbc507cb197a31322> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3373f000 - 0x33743fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33744000 - 0x337c6fff  MapKit armv7  <0aa2be229fc13ef091c124f5bdaff848> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x33d43000 - 0x33d8dfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33d96000 - 0x33db5fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <17803796ac1d31bdab85e651a74d5e0d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33dc0000 - 0x33dc4fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33dc5000 - 0x33dd4fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <083fb830455f3cd0869bf54bfd91108c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33e03000 - 0x33e07fff  FTClientServices armv7  <0f8bfadbf83a35c39f4ac39045ca569d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x33e12000 - 0x33edbfff  Celestial armv7  <f704f5baa8e932289bebd666acecebfa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33eeb000 - 0x33f1efff  MIME armv7  <c1ab6129b28b30c2a21cf33775bdf1d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33f26000 - 0x33f6ffff  CoreMedia armv7  <16e247e3f4a43fc5a72695092cf8ba96> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33f89000 - 0x33f91fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33f92000 - 0x33fa8fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <ff80b6648c24360583e5e624efda4815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x33ff2000 - 0x33ff7fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <49003f67c59730c9ac9c499517a3bb8b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3400a000 - 0x34097fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <2eb267ac3b5e32b0a43a61ccb98e6dd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3409c000 - 0x340a3fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <00599097fff03d02896974966dee6dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x340df000 - 0x34214fff  AudioCodecs armv7  <42b6bb9377df33309d1f691ce97035f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x34215000 - 0x34226fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <2306f236fe113baba3934f1884d36a47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34229000 - 0x3422afff  DataMigration armv7  <4179a9f217a8300d93c14b6fd87e5c31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3422b000 - 0x34242fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <7995d012ffbe394fb16888649b1e9742> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34472000 - 0x34476fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x345c1000 - 0x3466ffff  Message armv7  <4cc5b8bc0ec53e638635de6fe5ff12a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x346c9000 - 0x34885fff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34958000 - 0x34994fff  AppSupport armv7  <202262953e2d343cbf489fe1e308dba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34a24000 - 0x34ce5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34ce6000 - 0x34cf5fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34d27000 - 0x3526bfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35271000 - 0x3532cfff  AVFoundation armv7  <c971a925b82934f8881283aabb2992f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x35332000 - 0x35346fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <47b0ba3bcfd230a192119445de86cef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35347000 - 0x3534afff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x354bc000 - 0x354c1fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <11ce894432a73b9485cce6f5b1ea6488> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x354c4000 - 0x354fffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <1f70c1e94e333f0bb0866143b2abb0a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35500000 - 0x35500fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x35501000 - 0x35501fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x35508000 - 0x35517fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3559a000 - 0x35674fff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x35675000 - 0x35681fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x356f4000 - 0x35717fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3578a000 - 0x35796fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3579d000 - 0x357cdfff  ContentIndex armv7  <e610e7e8c8653d728dcc3c8fb471a994> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x357e3000 - 0x3580bfff  AppleAccount armv7  <f7d060ae5a7834bea114e9a3a032d3e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x3580c000 - 0x3580dfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35819000 - 0x35856fff  FTServices armv7  <9defdfb8c14239638d3a8efc9c4382de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35857000 - 0x358a0fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x358a1000 - 0x358fcfff  StoreServices armv7  <01e6b5e7449d39b8bc11e39fc217e645> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3598c000 - 0x3598efff  OAuth armv7  <c2a13b4c4dfd34efb60e89dafa87273c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x35992000 - 0x35993fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <77460820431837d68f19c81d53b6ca83> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x35b8f000 - 0x35b95fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x35bf3000 - 0x35bfcfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf524f1f6e8237369795867c7e2b4e67> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x35c93000 - 0x35c97fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <607095842baf3c41be3127ed773582ea> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35d0c000 - 0x35e8afff  Foundation armv7  <c1afe35de1f63b0db5b7ced0dec7163f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35f0e000 - 0x35f3afff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x35f3b000 - 0x35f45fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x35f85000 - 0x35f86fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36319000 - 0x3633cfff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3633d000 - 0x3633ffff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4c0648df13af341e88ddca80be687794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x363b5000 - 0x363f8fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3660f000 - 0x36615fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <8d5c3270e68e3dbbb2a72efd71314bf6> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x36636000 - 0x3670dfff  CFNetwork armv7  <794a80e086d23041bfdec139b01e80a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3670e000 - 0x36727fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3677f000 - 0x367fefff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cdd807e0d8523476b666a9dc63750bb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3680c000 - 0x36822fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36823000 - 0x3683cfff  Twitter armv7  <f9fe42c3e54835ccb2685e92d94c62fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x36934000 - 0x36937fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x36940000 - 0x36940fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x36941000 - 0x36947fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <19d7596821403d998017f03678d40514> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36988000 - 0x3699bfff  Notes armv7  <b2cb7346cb2b36eca53d22534c53b508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3699e000 - 0x3699efff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3699f000 - 0x369a5fff  XPCObjects armv7  <efaf263941313a1cb0e4908e46beee95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x36ac7000 - 0x36b40fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36b41000 - 0x36beefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36c18000 - 0x36c18fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36c49000 - 0x36c4cfff  ActorKit armv7  <8c167170891238b3940f9f54105b6eb9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x36c9c000 - 0x36cd1fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <68dbad71a3cc32e5941ad70820f88caa> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36d0b000 - 0x36d44fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36d45000 - 0x36d85fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36d86000 - 0x36dd0fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <7cb3680db3bb36a0b59b6d8e8cecf374> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36eda000 - 0x36f23fff  AddressBook armv7  <9ac3368232663b5786382e33c3773678> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x36f27000 - 0x36f28fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36f2b000 - 0x36f2cfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <1dadb6191d1835e5b078594218ce14f3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3700c000 - 0x37051fff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x37052000 - 0x37096fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <e05a113469ed345f98f306965abb30dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37134000 - 0x3713bfff  MailServices armv7  <a5e048e513b237b78d62fb3996a85fa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x372f9000 - 0x3766afff  TextInput armv7  <fbf47e8da82638568e5d2ebd6c47be68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x376da000 - 0x3774afff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3774d000 - 0x3775efff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <637167f4fa5c3cee99418295843e1580> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3775f000 - 0x378f7fff  CoreData armv7  <75030d6f36f9394592dd35af610e8960> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x37968000 - 0x3796dfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <ae0aa5856c093beaa792b34cafaa55df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x37971000 - 0x379bcfff  CoreLocation armv7  <77f81f93c6483079b547b3552b0247d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x379ee000 - 0x37a2bfff  IOKit armv7  <284ee3241c4a3b43b81b9ff514997013> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x37a38000 - 0x37c92fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <f1f929e78e753147bb4a638e95d29669> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37e22000 - 0x37ebafff  EventKit armv7  <77cfeb04c70c377aa484024bf2fbe980> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x380d0000 - 0x38121fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x38122000 - 0x3812efff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8e4095644cc33c97aa5f9f0620387f88> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3813c000 - 0x381e6fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x38253000 - 0x3839cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3839d000 - 0x3839dfff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x383bd000 - 0x3840efff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3840f000 - 0x3856cfff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x38572000 - 0x38577fff  ApplePushService armv7  <2e620a6e8ee8387ba2771cfd7870c90e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use an object that's been deallocated. Have you [enabled NSZombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211923/how-to-use-nszombie-in-xcode)? That would allow you to see which object you're trying to use and help you take care of the issue.

**EDIT**: In order to use NSZombies, you obviously need to run the app with the debugger enabled (I assume the crash log isn't from an external source, i.e. another user?).

Comment: I thought ARC meant you didn't need zombies? or do I have that totally backwards?

Comment: Yes, it is strange that you're getting memory errors, since ARC doesn't let/require you to retain and release objects. But you might have forgotten to define a `strong` reference on a property or something?

Answer (score 0):

This could still happen if you use the "Assign" property. Enable NSZombie and see if you set that property as assign instead of Weak or Strong.